# Add filter property to Yii2 yii\grid\ActionColumn class

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2

Currently there is no filter property in the Yii 2.0's actionColumn class, meaning you can not add content to the filter cell.

How can I extend the [yii\grid\actionColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html) class and add the filter property functionality that is in the [yii\grid\column](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html) class so I can move my clear-filter button from the header to filter cell?

[image: Gridview Filter and Header Cells]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you can just create a new class extending the `ActionColumn` class like this:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\grid\ActionColumn;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class MyActionColumn extends ActionColumn
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function renderFilterCellContent()
    {
        return Html::button('Clear Filter');
    }

}
```

Then you can use this class in your column definition like this:

`'class' => 'app\components\MyActionColumn'`

which will add your button to every column where you are using this new class.

Obviously you can add a lot more functionality and customise it even further.

Hope it helps...